# What does "a good laugh" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

> I definitely enjoy spending time with my family. I feel like I'm a very down to earth person who enjoys **a good laugh**. I've never been good at things like this, so if you have any questions, feel free to ask!

Is "a good laugh" an idiom? Does it always mean a partner? Or does it literally mean a happy life?

Comment: Such a good laugh means enjoyable

Comment: You're stretching, a good laugh is a laugh that is very enjoyable, no need to look further.

Answer (score 5):

A good laugh it is an idiom. I don't see how it could mean "a partner". In this context it simply means *"to have fun while telling/hearing some funny stuff`"*.

It could also mean *to make fun of something*:

> We had a good laugh after she fell on the floor.

Another example which is connected to this idiom would be:

> They cranked me up with that joke, I had a good laugh.

Which translates to: *That joke made me laugh, it was a good one*.

Comment: I think the "partner" part might come from the fact that this excerpt was taken from the profile of a dating website (at least, that's what it looks like).

Answer (score 0):

You can 'Have a good laugh' without being told a joke or ever laughing out loud.  It just means you had a jolly, light-hearted time.  If @J.R is right about the quote being from a dating website (which seems very possible) I'd take it as a version of 'GOSH'  (Good Sense Of Humour).  It would be overthinking to extend this into 'ONLY wants a good time' ) i.e. 'nothing serious', though the inference could be there.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, this is clearly from a dating profile or very similar.
In this case, the best alternative I can come up with to replace `enjoys a good laugh` is `has a good sense of humour`  or the more stilted: `enjoys fun`